# “Sich anhören wie” or “sich anhören als”?

Tags: preposition

If you translate *it sounded like laughter* into German, would it be more correct to say:

> Es hörte sich *wie* Lachen an

or

> Es hörte sich *als* Lachen an

?

Answer (score 4):

The only correct way to say it is *sich **wie** etwas anhören*.

The phrase is analogous to *es klingt wie ein Lachen* whose usage can be found in dictionaries. I am soundly surprised that I didn’t find *sich wie etwas anhören* in the dictionaries I quickly checked.

*Als* usually implies something to be different from something else in some way, which is why in standard German comparatives are connected with *als*:

> Es hört sich *anders als* ein Lachen an.

*Wie* often (but not as usually when compared to *als*) implies the similarity. However, especially in colloquial South German, *wie* is used where *als* might be more appropriate. In any case, your example is comparing *similarities*, so it should be *wie*.

> Es hört sich *wie* Lachen an.

Comment: Contrast with _Es hört sich an, als ob jemand lacht._